# Command to refresh output of other command

Tags: bash, command, refresh

If I have a command that each time gives me a output, (a status, for example). How I can do it to refresh this output every 2 seconds, for example? I remember that there is one command which can do it.

Example:

```
cat /proc/mdstat 

[======>..............]  resync = 30.8% (150544832/488383936) finish=65.8min speed=85472K/sec

othercommand cat /proc/mdstat
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're looking for the `watch` command.

---

Example from [FrankyFred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540380/frankyfred):

```
watch -n 5 free -m
```

will refresh the `free -m` command every 5s

Comment: Example `watch -n 5 free -m`
(refresh every 5s the `free -m` command)